# Why there's no data when tracking site performance?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics and I'd like to track also my site's performance, but I keep getting no data. Is there anything what should I do with my tracking code?
I tried to set sample rate to 100%, but with no results. I've searched a lot,but didn't find any help.
 Here's my tracking code:

```
<script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'xx-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        ga('create', 'xx-xxxxxxx-x', { 'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100 });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked out the realtime statistics page in analytics? Are you sure there any visitors on your website? Does the realtime statistics show any if you visit your website while having the realtime statistics open?

Comment: Yes it does. Other statistics works well. I've got about 2000 pagewiews last week. But in Behaviour>SiteSpeed>Overview It reads "0 of pageviews sent page load sample"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the create method only once.
 So you'd have to replace the line

```
ga('create', 'xx-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
```

For

```
ga('create', 'xx-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto', { 'siteSpeedSampleRate': 1 });
```

It's an object you pass to the create method in which you may set multiple options.
As Philip pointed out in the comments: 'auto' sets the tracking to the toplevel-domain (without it subdomains eon't be tracked).

More examples are given here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced?hl=nl

Comment: Great, I'm looking forward to the outcome. I'm actually not a 100% sure on this one, although when reading the documentation it seems logical to call the create method only once :)

Comment: No, 'auto' is **NOT** the default. You should change that line to `ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-X', 'auto', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});`. 'auto' sets the cookie to the top level domain, the default uses `location.hostname`. If you remove 'auto' then subdomain tracking won't work.

Comment: Ok interesting point there Philip, thanks. I haven't actually dived into the documentation, but only looked at it quickly. I edited my answer with your addition.